# ssl access in web API ASP.Net Core 2

Tags: ssl, asp.net-core-2.0

I want to force the access to my web API with SSL

In Visual Studio I see this
[image: api]

The to force the calls to use https I have this

```
.UseRewriter(new RewriteOptions().AddRedirectToHttps(301,44329))
```

But when I make this call for example: http://localhost:5001/api/proyectos that until now worked fine. Now this call is translated to https://localhost:44329/api/proyectos and the page is nod loaded.

Any idea please?

Comment: How did you make calls of the above urls ? I configured the properties of my asp.net core 2.1 project like the showed picture and add the code into `Configure` method , then tested the urls using postman , both they worked and the breakpoint in the action is hit .

Comment: Sorry I don't understand the question. If I use .AddRedirect all the calls are traslated to https://localhost:44329 and all the call that without https works fine now does not respond